# Displaying "Correct" and "Wrong" in JAVA

Tags: java, checkbox, settext

I'm making a simple quiz program. I need to display my Correct and Wrong it depends on the answer of the user. I think it is in the IF else. That's why I can't get it through. When I run it. I choose the correct answer. It is still displaying "Wrong!" and it counts it as correct. and Then change to different number. It is still displaying "Wrong!". I'm using checkbox as the multiple choice of the quiz.
Here's my code:

```
    if(C1.getState()) // if the user chooses the checkbox c1
{
    outputlabel.setText("Correct\n");
    CorrectAnswer++; // it will count one point per correct answer.
    }else 
    outputlabel.setText("Wrong!\n");

    if(C13.getState()) // if the user chooses the checkbox C13
    {
outputlabel.setText("Correct\n");
    CorrectAnswer++;
    }else 
    outputlabel.setText("Wrong!\n");

    if(C19.getState()) // if the user chooses the checkbox C19
    {
outputlabel.setText("Correct\n");
    CorrectAnswer++;
    }else 
    outputlabel.setText("Wrong!\n");
if(C21.getState()) // if the user chooses the checkbox C21  
{
outputlabel.setText("Correct\n");
CorrectAnswer++;
    }else 
    outputlabel.setText("Wrong!\n");

    if(C27.getState()) // if the user chooses the checkbox C27
    {
    outputlabel.setText("Correct\n");
    CorrectAnswer++;
    }else 
    outputlabel.setText("Wrong!\n");

    CorrectLabel.setText("Correct Answers: "+CorrectAnswer);

    score =(CorrectAnswer*100)/5; // average of the quiz
    if (score>=75)
    {
    scorelabel.setText("Grade: "+score+ "% ");    
    }else{
    scorelabel.setText("Grade: "+score+"%.");

repaint();}

    }

    }
```

Comment: Could you provide an executable code snippet, so I can test?

Comment: The code is fine. My guess is the method getState doesn't do what you think it does. Print a line with the result of a getState. Plus, the score should be calculated as CorrectAnswer*5, otherwise it will never be over 75 (you'll get a max score of 5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do in the code. For each you're checking if it is set, and then you're setting the outputlabel value. So if the *first* checkbox is checked it will set the outputlabel text to "Correct". And if *any* of the other checkboxes are *not* checked it will then simply override what you did before and set the label to "Wrong".

Maybe you want separate outputlabels for each of the checkboxes?

Comment: In addition, `if(C??.getState()) // if the user chooses the checkbox C??
    {
    outputlabel.setText("Correct\n");
    CorrectAnswer++;
    }else 
    outputlabel.setText("Wrong!\n");` seems to be copy-pasta. I suggest putting it in a separate method. Your checkboxes could go into a container, like an array or `List`.

Answer (score 0):

You should have one final output label, after you check the state of all the correct answers. And based on the correct answers count, you can set the final output label.